# JetBrains company editors, can not input Chinese symbols

Tags: phpstorm, symbols, jetbrains-ide

PHPstorm9 and Pycharm 4.5.4

maybe change the settings, or accidentally press a shortcut key,

Input is the **(,.)**

can not input Chinese symbols**（，。）**

Comment: maybe it's your keyboard input settings? have you check them?

Comment: Do not modify the keyboard input settings , in the browser and other APP  is normal _ (: з) ∠) _

Comment: PHPstorm 9.0.2  and Pycharm 4.5.4 ，
Can't input Chinese symbols：“（，。）；”
If i want input “（，。）；”， Must input “（，。）； ”in other APP or Browser copy-and-paste to the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a JDK issue, please see [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142652#comment=27-1064707).